# Dynamic library link issue (32-bit and 64-bit)in Solaris 10

Tags: linker, 64-bit, solaris, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

all:
    There are 2 dynamic libraries in my Solaris:

```
/usr/local/lib/amd64/libhiredis.so (64-bit)
/usr/local/lib/libhiredis.so (32-bit)
```

I want to compile my 64-bit program, so I should link the /usr/local/lib/amd64/libhiredis.so.

I use the 2 methods:

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -m64 -o monitor monitor.c -L/usr/local/lib/amd64 -lhiredis -lpthread -lrt -lsocket -lnsl -lresolv
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -m64 -o monitor monitor.c /usr/local/lib/amd64/libhiredis.so -lpthread -lrt -lsocket -lnsl -lresolv
```

But I find the program always linked with /usr/local/lib/libhiredis.so (32-bit). I don't know the cause.

Could anyone help me? Thanks very much!

Best Regards
Nan Xiao

Comment: How are you checking to see what the program is linked with?  `elfdump -d` and `ldd -v` are very useful to help track down issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

> But I find the program always linked with /usr/local/lib/libhiredis.so (32-bit).

No, you **don't** find that.

You find something else, which you *mis*-interpret to mean that you linked with the 32-bit library.

Comment: I fix the issue by using the following methods:  
    (1) Add the /usr/local/lib/amd64 in LD_LIBRARY_PATH;  
    (2) /usr/sfw/bin/gcc -m64 -g -o redismonitor redis_monitor.c -L/usr/local/lib/amd64 -R/usr/local/lib/amd64 -lhiredis -lpthread -lrt -lsocket -lnsl -lresolv